# Where is the config.local.php in magento 2.1

Tags: magento-2.1, upgrade, magento2.2, cloud, magento-upgrade

According to the magento 2 upgrade to 2.1.7 to 2.2 they highlighted "config.local.php" file. I cant find it, can anyone know where is it ? 
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/cloud/project/project-upgrade.html

Answer (score 0):

This information details how to upgrade **Magento Commerce (Cloud)** to 2.2.X from any version, and upgrading to new 2.2.X versions.

Note: Only Magento Commerce (Cloud), not for CE or EE.

Comment: Actually cloud is not easy thing lot of restrictions. cant run composer using ssh , git is the only way :(

Answer (score 0):

you can find this file in following  folders:

```
\vendor\magento\module-config\Test\Unit\Model\Config\_files
```

Hope it will help you!
Thanks

Comment: your magento is working fine on every panel?